# how to display multiple images with y scrollbar in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am totally new to tkinter and I am trying to dispaly multiple images that the user can scroll to see them all here my best try:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

n = 128
path = "/media/mark/B37B-0280/img5/test/mm"
images = []
photos = []
cas = []
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0)
names = [name for name in os.listdir(path)]
images = [Image.open(path + "/" + name).resize((n, n)) for name in names]
photos = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(image) for image in images]
canvas = Canvas(frame, bg="yellow", width=n*len(names), height=n*len(names))
canvas.grid(row=0, sticky="news")
cas = [Canvas(canvas, width=n, height=n) for p in photos]

i = 0
for c, im in zip(cas, photos):
    c.create_image(n/2, n/2, image=im)
    c.grid(row=i)
    i += 1
vsb = Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
root.mainloop()
```

as you see there is a scroll bar but not working, what is wrong? how to fix it?

The images are displayed properly but the scrolling is not working

Comment: What exactly isn't working? are the images displayed properly, and just the scrolling doesn`t work, or what's your specific problem?

Comment: @Flob yes the images are displayed properly but the scrolling does not work

Comment: I did an edit on my answer, it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As explained in the answer to and comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222125/canvas-bbox-method-returns-none-although-widgets-exist-inside), widgets that are placed inside a canvas are not automatically canvas items. For this, a `canvas.create_window`command needs to be used, as explained [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method). I will edit my code at the end of this answer to make it work as intended.

---

When adding a `Scrollbar`to a `Canvas`in tkinter, it can be necessary to pass an additional argument called `scrollregion` - the Canvas has to "know" which part of it's coordinate system you want to scroll to. So adding

```
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))
```

should make it work as intended.
`canvas.bbox`specifies a region ([bounding box](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pythondoc-tkinter-canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method)) of the canvas, `ALL` simply specifies the bounding box for all items.

Apart from that, just a few general hints: you can remove the

```
images = []
photos = []
cas = []
```

part in your code, because you define these lists later anyway. Also, even creating these lists isn't necessary (at least with how your code is structured right now, if you need to do something with them later it can of course be useful), you can put all of that inside one loop (Code not tested!) **now edited**:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

n = 128
path = "/media/mark/B37B-0280/img5/test/mm"
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=n*number, height=n*number).grid(row=0)

number = len(os.listdir(path))
canvas = Canvas(frame, bg="yellow", width=n*number, height=n*number)

i = 0
for name in os.listdir(path):
    image = Image.open(path + "/" + name).resize((n, n))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    c = Canvas(canvas, width=n, height=n)
    c.create_image(n/2, n/2, image=photo)
    canvas.create_window(0, n*i, window=c)
    i += 1

vsb = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL)
vsb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
vsb.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(width=n * number, height=n * number)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vsb.set, scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))
canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: all what I get now is gray window with scrollbar but no images that is weird

Comment: I had to change  Canvas(canvas, w=n, h=n) to  Canvas(canvas, width=n, height=n) but not showing the images now any idea?

Comment: if you use all of your original code, and just add `canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))`, does it work? i didn't get to test my answer yet, so it could be that i slipped an error into the code...

Comment: I tried your code after you edited it still no images appear in the window and all I got is gray window and scrollbar with nothing else. I noticed that bbox is returning none.

Comment: Just a sec to try

Comment: it works if I add canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set, scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL)) to my original code but the scrollbar still does not work. note: canvas.bbox(ALL) returns none is this have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: what does `canvas.bbox()` without any arguments return?

Comment: self.tk.call((self._w, 'bbox') + args)) or None
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".140256781064456.140256752795304 bbox tagOrId ?tagOrId ...?"

Comment: I think we have to pass some kind of argument to canvas.bbox

Comment: Make sure you set the scroll region after creating the images, not before. The bounding box of the items on a canvas will be `None` if there's nothing on the canvas.

Comment: @BryanOakley I do set the scroll region after creating images

Comment: I'm sorry, that's really odd... you see, `bbox` takes item specifiers as an argument and returns 4 coordinates (e.g. a rectangle) that represent the bounding position of the specified items on the Canvas. The specifier `ALL` refers to every single item that has been drawn on the canvas. So as soon as there is anything on the canvas, it MUST return something. In your case, there is a number of `len(photos)` different canvases inside the big canvas at the time you set the scrollregion, so it seems impossible for me that `bbox` should return `None`... I'm sorry,  i can't help you with that.

Comment: Okay, so apparently, there is a "[bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue210824)" with `canvas.bbox` that happens when the canvas bounding box exceeds the maximum integer value, which is 2^31 on most computers, because tkinter uses integers instead of floats for canvas bounds (for whatever reason). The internal exception handling for this `OverflowError` is returning an empty string, which leads to `canvas.bbox(ALL)` returning `None`.

Comment: Ookay i figured it out: you have no canvas items inside your canvas - you just have other canvases managed by `grid`, which are not considered to be canvas items. So you have to use `canvas.create_window(...` etc. as explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222125/canvas-bbox-method-returns-none-although-widgets-exist-inside)